# Make simple query

Tags: mysql

I have my sql query which very complexion and day by day data of table geeting larger so executions of query getting larger so i need to optimist my query.
please Help

my query is

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
        WHERE col1 NOT IN (
        SELECT col1 FROM data_visit_aavaas 
        GROUP BY col1 HAVING COUNT(*) >1) 
        AND add_date Like '2017-05-18' 
        ORDER BY add_date ASC
```

Comment: Suggest you define an index on `(col1)` in `data_visit_aavaas` and an index on `(add_date, col1)` in `tablename`.

Comment: `SELECT * .... GROUP BY col1` is bad SQL and makes MySQL select wrong values... read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Please share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` outputs

Comment: Looks too me `ORDER BY add_date ASC` is not needed you only select one date `add_date Like '2017-05-18' `

Comment: How can one date be 'like' another date?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` and `DATE` function to make MySQL use index, e.g.:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t
WHERE DATE(t.add_date) = '2017-05-18' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM data_visit_aavaas WHERE col1 = t.col1
);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland order what? can't see any `order by` in the answer ;)